# Filtering GetEntries by another Entry ID's existence within array of links attribute

Tags: contentful

I have a content type `post` where the entries have a `categories` attribute, which is an Array of Links (to a `category` content type).

I want to fetch all `post`s that have been tagged with a certain `category`.  That is, Post entries where fields.categories[any link sys.id] = MyCategoryId.

I can only find an example only where the reference field is a singleton, not an array.

Would love any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could specify your query like this:

```
/spaces/YOURSPACEID/entries?content_type=CONTENTTYPEID&fields.categories.sys.id=SOMEID
```

Notice that a content type restriction is necessary as we are filtering on a field property.

Also note that this only works because we're filtering on a system property directly accessible from the actual entry returned. If you wanted to filter on another property of the Category content type, for example `title` or `description` that is not currently supported.

Here's also a link to the official documentation including examples and explanations for the search api: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/query-entries